# Проблема с запуском рабочего окружения на kubuntu после установки vns

Tags: linux, kubuntu

Во время установки vns не стал скачивать окружение рабочего стола и создавать отдельного пользователя. После установки перезагрузил компьютер и вижу, что рабочий стол не загружается. Попробовал запустить через  терминал vns и подключиться. Подключился через смартфон и вижу свой рабочий стол. Отключил все, удалил vns. Пытаюсь зайти в систему, ничего. Как решить проблему? Мне кажется, что при установке vns закошмарил настройки sddm.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в sddm. Как я понял это баг самого менеджера, поэтому решил поставить lightdm. С gmd3 работает тоже.